# Decomposition of altitude using vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

In a triangle $ABC$ we consider the height $AD$ from the vertex $A (D \in BC)$. Find the
decomposition of the vector $AD$ in terms of the vectors $\vec c =\vec {AB} $  and $\vec b = \vec {AC}$. Can somebody give me some tips, please?

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: I don't have any attemps. I think this may go directly having a good idea.